# Add data to another table whenever user registers - laravel

Tags: laravel

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $image = new Image;
    $image->current_step =  'step1';
    $image->isCompleted = '0';
    $image->save();

}
```

Whenever the user first registers, I'm looking to input a bunch of data into another table. The user can register fine but whenever I check the database nothing is in the other table.

Is this going in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: `return` will prevent the execution of any code following it; you've got what's known as "unreachable" code in your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove your first return:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([ // <-- HERE
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $image = new Image;
    $image->current_step =  'step1';
    $image->isCompleted = '0';
    $image->save();

    return $user;
}
```

The rest of your code is unreachable because of `return`.

Comment: This has worked. Thanks for the replying, I'll know for the future.